# How to get number of lines from RDD which contain any digits

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Lines of the document as follows:

```
I am 12 year old.

I go to school.

I am playing.

Its 4 pm.
```

There are two lines of the document that contain numbers in them. I want to count how many lines are there in the document with number?

This is to be implemented in scala spark.

```scala
 val lineswithnum=linesRdd.filter(line => (line.contains([^0-9]))).count()
```

I expect output to be 2 . But I am getting 0

Comment: Your question and title differ, I am changing that.

Comment: I m surprised no credit for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists` method:

```scala
val lineswithnum=linesRdd.filter(line => line.exists(_.isDigit)).count()
```

Comment: `filter(cond).count()` may be replaced by `count(cond)`

Comment: @MikhailIonkin In what version? [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@count():Long) doesn't seem to be overloaded. Have I missed some implicits somewhere (didn't try it out...)?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Ah, indeed, title was changed... Didn't notice that. :]

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, sorry, I think that it is common collection, like [Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/Seq.html), not RDD. thebluephantom says that he change something

Comment: The title did not match the question. It now matches the text but looking back may be it is the negation i.e. both ways of the 4 the answer would be both 2.

Comment: Saving grace that the correction was correct is val lineswithnum

Answer (score 0):

In line with your original approach and not discounting the other answer(s):

```
val textFileLines = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/so99.txt")
val linesWithNumCollect = textFileLines.filter(_.matches(".*[0-9].*")).count
```

The .* added so as to capture within a line string.